# Stable ShareKit fork recommendation?

Tags: ios, sharekit

[ShareKit](https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit) looks abandoned. And there are so many forks. But major maintainer is undeterminable. Now I'm just going to pick one to use. What fork do you recommend? Or replacement?

Answer (score 8):

try [ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit), they are trying to make the ultimate "best of" fork. ShareKit release 2.0 is in final testing.

Comment: I have downloaded Sharekit 2.0 and it is showing a trillion errors on Xcode 4, not to mention several files missing.

Comment: RubberDuck, make sure to follow ShareKit install wiki. You most probably do not have submodules files.

Answer (score 3):

[Socialize](http://www.getsocialize.com/) is a new social sharing sdk by the folks behind AppMakr. It's open source and appears to be free. I haven't tried it yet - so I can't vouch for it - but maybe it's worth a look?

Comment: It looks good. Can I use only 'sharing' feature without any other feature?

Comment: According to their web site you can use just the features you want and leave out the rest. Also note that the sharing feature currently supports just Facebook, Twitter and Email - whereas ShareKit supported many more sharing methods.

Answer (score 1):

As of lately, ShareKit hasn't been working on iOS5 so I had to remove it from my app.  Facebook has actually released their own class and it's looking pretty sharp so far.  Check it out:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: Thanks for letting me know ShareKit is not working anymore. It's sad :(

Comment: You betcha!  Sharekit was nice when it first came around, but there are better things these days and we need to move on ;)

Comment: Oh @Alex, can you recommend some of better solutions? It will be really helpful to me :)

Comment: that's the best solution I can recommend :).  there are others but they'll quickly become outdated.  what kind of issues are you having with facebook's class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the last official release in my application. Works fine though. You can just add new social networks to the kit yourself if needed.