# Which one is the best clone of ShareKit for iPhone Development?

Tags: iphone, facebook, sdk, sharekit

ShareKit is a really nice and easy sharing solution to knock off iPhone App project without frustrations for developers. However, it seems the original github repo is not updated and there are 40 pull requests are not merged. I also resolved a few issues by myself, like iOS5/iOS4 compatibility and Cancel Button bugs. But other developers solved issues and I guess they have their own brunches. So, who maintains the best ShareKit clone in github?

https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) - it is a community effort that pulls together the best parts of the most popular forks.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solid version! I also found the similar discussion here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703745/stable-sharekit-fork-recommendation

Comment: Kiichi, two questions: (1) How did you fix the cancel button bugs? I'm having a problem with Facebook and can't fix it (one really bad hack may work, but I'm looking for a better solution)? (2) Have you had any problems with FB in the 2.0 version? I keep getting "can't open page, url invalid" problem. I don't like being redirected to Safari.

Comment: @Kiichi Takeuchi, to clarify, I'm wondering how to fixed the cancel button in the older version of ShareKit.

Comment: OK, ShareKit2.0 is also problematic. I came back to original ShareKit and this is how I fixed the cancel button for iOS5.

In SHK.m, change two lines that contains following method

dismissModalViewControllerAnimated

to
if ([currentView respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)])
            [[currentView presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NO];
else
            [[currentView parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];